# How to add a new unit of measure in Maximo?

Tags: units-of-measurement, maximo

I would like to add a new unit of measure to Maximo 7.6.1 (Maximo Asset Management).

Is it possible to do this?

I found this article: [Adding units of measure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWT9A_7.6.1/com.ibm.mbs.doc/mbs_common/t_add_units_measure.html). But it seems like it applies to something other than *Maximo Asset Management*.

Comment: The article applies to IBM Control Desk, which, like Maximo Asset Management (aka MAM or Maximo), is effectively an add-on to Tivoli Process Automation Engine (TPAE) (aka Maximo Base Services). In fact, Maximo v6 installed both MAM and ICD and you had to then install "keys" for the one you were licensed for. Therefore, articles about base functionality, like the one mentioned, tend to also apply to Maximo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Inventory application click on "Unit of Measure and Conversion" in the menu on the left hand side of the screen then "Add/Modify Units of Measure" and "Add/Modify Conversions" as required.